# login to phpBB using curl

Tags: python, php, node.js, curl, web-scraping

I want to login using curl to a phpBB forum.

I'm testing my script of loggin in on https://forums.linuxmint.com/ucp.php?mode=login

you can test it there too.

I don't want to make this question complicated, so I'll not write code here, so everybody python, javascript, php, java or any other folks can answer this question.

here is what I did:

1. create a file on the desktop called `cookie.txt`
2. open the terminal (I'm using linux with bash shell by the way)
3. I wrote this command and I hit enter

```sh
curl -b ~/Desktop/cookie.txt -c ~/Desktop/cookie.txt -X POST -F "username=YOUR_USER_NAME" -F 'password=YOUR_PASSWORD' "https://forums.linuxmint.com/ucp.php?mode=login"
```

4. Here is the screenshot from `~/Desktop/cookie.txt`:
   [image]
5. I requested a page that require users to be logged in, [here is one](https://forums.linuxmint.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=62313)

```sh
curl -b ~/Desktop/cookie.txt -c ~/Desktop/cookie.txt "https://forums.linuxmint.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=62313"
```

6. I read the output, and it's not working.

- How did I know that it doesn't work?

A) just look at the page `<title>`, in the response of curl in the terminal, the `<title>` is **Linux Mint Forums - Login**, which means that the login is not successful for some reason.

anyone knows can help? any answer is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post pictures, just paste the text. 
To cite from the curl docs for the cookie file: "Lines that start with # are treated as comments." So you basically have only comments in your file.

Comment: so. ? what should I do? curl wrote that it's not me, I'm showing the file to you to see the what happened, yes I know that the lines with # are comments

Comment: You are sending an empty cookie, so it can't work. Just compare with the cookie which is used normally when you log in, e.g. via Dev Tools in the browser.